# Npm install brings in packages, but they cant be found after successfully (?) installing

Tags: npm, jasmine, node-modules, global, package-managers

I'm trying to npm install a package (jasmine) for a project. The package seems to install just fine, however when I attempt use it I'm met with an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD02E.png). I'm installing the package globally, so it should be accessible and I can see it in [my node modules folder as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT5sh.png). I'm relatively new to using package managers and I'm stumped as to the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

When Cygwin or WSL start up, they take in the path value from Windows, so what you're seeing is a problem that stems from Cygwin looking for node in the Windows path and not the Cygwin path.
If you can remove node from your Windows install, your Cygwin install dhijnd pick up the right executable, and start working as expected.